# git log - line too long - no line break

Tags: git

(Using Debian Linux, KDE, Konsole and bash.)

When I run git log, I can't read the full commit message. I see the beginning of the sentence but if it's too long, I can't see it.

Also I am not seeing entries with multiple lines.

How can I see the full git log entry?

Comment: Do you have any settings (e.g. in your `.gitconfig`) that change the default format of `git log`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to force the default log style, do

```
git log --format=medium
```

Answer (score 8):

did you try pressing the right-arrow button to see those long lines?

Comment: I can use the left and right arrows to see the log line, but how do I get the command-line to let me enter a new command?

Comment: @WEFX press q. The program you are looking at after runnig `git log` is called `less`. Wikipedia has a [quick overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29#Frequently_used_commands)

Answer (score 5):

`git log | cat` is always a nice trick.

Comment: This one worked for me. Any of the other solutions I've read haven't. Thanks! (2.5 years later...)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git config --global core.pager 'less -R'
```

Note this prevents less from keeping track of the screen appearance, which can lead to various display problems, one of which is long lines being split in the wrong places (which is the side effect we *want*)